# Escaping single quote in PHP

Tags: php, escaping, html-entities

I have an admin page which handles adding of product. I used [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on protecting my database from unnecessary characters. But when I get these data from the database (e.g. product name with single quote like Dave's Box), I had a error when displaying it on my page in the [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) attribute.

I used this code for displaying the product code.

```
echo "<li onClick='fill(\"$productName\")'><strong>".stripslashes($row['name'])."</strong> by ".stripslashes($row['brand'])."</li>";
```

Comment: **What error you get and what HTML code caused it?**. Can you post HTML code, not PHP code?

Comment: also, get rid of stripslashes(), it's wrong to use it here

Answer (score 1):

You should protect your code from quotes, dbl-quotes and HTML tags. To do that use PHP's [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) with `ENT_QUOTES` set. Example:

```
 htmlspecialchars($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode` for the product name in the javascript function call, and `htmlspecialchars` for the normal HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

To subsume the other answers:

- use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to encode the `$productName` value properly as JavaScript string and
- use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) with the quote style *ENT_QUOTES* to encode it properly to be used in a single quotes HTML attribute value.

So:

```
echo "<li onClick='" . htmlspecialchars('fill('.json_encode($productName).')', ENT_QUOTES) . "'><strong>" . htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['name'])) . "</strong> by " . htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['brand'])) . "</li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use addslashes() and possibly htmlentities() depending on the type of valid product names you allow.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php